# Multithreaded Worker Pattern

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, httpwebrequest, client-server

I'm not sure about the exact name of that pattern (code sample), but I'm sure it exists.
I have a class which works as a client and connects to the server.
I would like to run it in multithreaded. But here is the trick.
I want to keep track of the time it takes to complete whole process operation per thread.
And if operation time is in the specified bound, then more threads should be started and so on
until there too much threads and speed goes lower.

Am I clear?

Please advise...

Answer (score 2):

You can't make an individual request complete faster by adding more threads.

Also, if all your requests are to the same server, you may actually slow down the server by making multiple concurrent requests. Quite apart from other considerations like hitting the maximum number of concurrent connections.

So, it's more complex than just `"run it in multithreaded"`!

Comment: Nevertheless, I need this solution. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The key to patterns is it's not about just one.

It sounds like you want a `TaskListener` that listens for `taskStarted` and `taskFinished` events, which may use a `TaskProfiler` which will determine if that `Task` completed in an appropriate amount of time. (It may also want to `Visit` the `Task` to ascertain more details about it, if your thresholds are not uniform for all tasks)

From there it sounds like you then want a `TaskExecutor` which will notify the `TaskListener` when it starts and finishes a particular task.

The `TaskExecutor` might make available `increaseWorkerPool` and `decreaseWorkerPool` methods which can be adjusted by a `TaskAdministrator` which receives feedback from the profiler/listener.

This is mostly demonstrative, you might just want to pass the task completion time as part of a single, `taskComplete(Task task, long millis)` method.

All of that having been said, "spawn threads until it doesn't work very good" isn't the most heuristic of load balancing techniques...